# Can't make ng-view work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I'm new to angular and trying to learn it, so I guess this is a pretty basic question,

I am trying to use ng-view, so far with no success.

this is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <script src="~/scripts/refernces/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="~/scripts/refernces/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/refernces/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../scripts/App/myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='navbar-header'>
         <a class='navbar-header' href='Home'>Demo Site</a>
      </div>
    <div>
   <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='active'><a href='#Home'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='/#About'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='/#Contact'>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href='/#Other'>Other</a></li></ul></div</div></nav>"
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when("#About", {
        template: '<h1>about</h1>'
    })
        .when("Contact",
    {
        template: '<h1>Contact</h1>'
    });   
});
```

I've tried declaring 'when' with and without the '#' sign, and I know Angular is loading fine (I have a controller that acts as I expect and I don't have any errors in the console) but I can't seem to make the routing work.

Tnx

Comment: Could you provide a plunker?

Comment: try using the `$stateprovider` in combination with `ui-sref="state1"` and watch out with the html5mode this can become a pain in the ass if set to true. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: than wouldn't  i need to switch to use ui-router instead of ngRoute and change ng-view to ui-view?

Comment: @jordy tnx a lot i changed to ui-router and ui-sref and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $locationProvider.html5Mode to true, you need to add:

```
<base href="/">
```

in the head of the document.

Also you do not need to use the hash in the href.

So give this code a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Hello world</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <a class='navbar-header' href='Home'>Demo Site</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                <li class='active'><a href='Home'>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href='/About'>About</a></li>
                <li><a href='/Contact'>Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href='/Other'>Other</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div
    </div>
</nav>

<div ng-view></div>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider.when("/About", {
                    template: '<h1>about</h1>'
                })
                .when("/Contact",
                        {
                            template: '<h1>Contact</h1>'
                        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: it's working gr8t with html5mode set to true (although I actually switched to use ui-router instead of ngRoute). tnx

Answer (score 1):

You are actually pretty close, first off, one small typo in your html:

```
<<li><a href='/#Other'>Other</a></li></ul></div</div></nav>
                                              ^^^ missing end caret
```

Next up, we can talk about ngRoute's HTML5 mode. You explicitly set HTML5 mode to true, which means that angular is going to attempt to use all links you provide it as actual URLs, instead of append a URL fragment (`#fake/url/here`) to the current url and using that for routing. THe difference looks like this:

HTML5 mode == true

```
http://yoursite.com/angularPage/Contact
http://yoursite.com/angularPage/About
```

HTML5 mode == false

```
http://yoursite.com/angularPage#/Contact
http://yoursite.com/angularPage#/About
```

Looking at your HTML, I guessed that since you were using the `#` character, you did not want to use HTML5 mode, so I modified your stuff to look like this. Note how I changed the links, and your routeProvider.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='navbar-header'>
         <a class='navbar-header' href='Home'>Demo Site</a>
      </div>
    <div>
   <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
      <li class='active'><a href='#Home'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#About'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#Contact'>Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href='#Other/Page'>Other</a></li></ul></div></div></nav>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

JS

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    $routeProvider.when("/About", {
        template: '<h1>about</h1>'
    })
        .when("/Contact",
    {
        template: '<h1>Contact</h1>'
    })
        .when("/Other/Page",
    {
        template: '<h1>OtherPage</h1>'
    });   
});
```

Check the fragment syntax, and not how the routeProvider essentially parses your `#Other/Page` into `/Other/Page`. Also note the lack of a `/` before the links in your `<a>` tags, a `/` there means an absolute link, which would replace your current navigation tree.

Comment: i actually do want to use html5mode true just wasn't sure how to do it, both answers are great and if possible i would mark the both as accepted